# How to get a list of many to many relation to the same model

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many, relationship

I want to move the list of related messages with a given model to the variable in the view - this is the "related" field.
At the moment I'm getting all the objects that are badly displayed on the site.

Please any hint, thanks a lot.

Model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    link_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    related = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'news'
        ordering = ['-date']
```

View:

```
class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.News
    context_object_name = 'news_item'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['related_news'] = models.News.objects.values_list('related', flat=True)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `self.object` variable that is given to you by the `DetailView`:

```
context['related_news'] = self.object.related.all()  # [1]
```

so that in your template you can iterate over the elements:

```
{% for related_item in related_news %}
    {{ related_item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

[1] `self.object` is defined by the time `get_context_data()` is called

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is working :) +1 @dirkgroten